# multiple classes css selector not working with :hover

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following css selector that is not working:

```
.button.button-green:hover
```

however if I do this, it works fine:

```
.button-green:hover
```

Is this a known issue with CSS and are there any ways around this (besided just using one class for the hover)?

Comment: In which browser? It seems [fine to me](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/M96HV/) in Chrome.

Comment: Working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/SWKTP/ ... can you show an example? What browser?

Comment: `.button.button-green:hover` is a valid selector. Need to see your HTML, otherwise all you're going to get is handwaving back at you.

Comment: did you mean `button.button-green:hover` ? No? Does `.button` possibly have `background-image` and your changing just the `background-color` on hover? Is `.button` using `!important` in any of it's properties? There are many possibilities, and a bug seems the least likely to me. I refer you to BoltClock's comment

Answer (score 0):

See the following jsbin for a few different options:
http://jsbin.com/akowix/1/

What does your html look like?

- Do you have an element with both the "button" class and the "button-green" class?
- Or do you have an element with the "button" class that contains an element with the "button-green" class?
- Or do you have two different elements, one with the "button" class and one with the "button-green" class that you want the hover rule applied to both?

Comment: You may as well post this as a comment instead.

Comment: @BoltClock - Yes, you are right. I originally intended to copy some of the code from the jsbin example, but ended up scrapping that idea since it's not clear what the OP actually wants. I figured the example in the jsbin was worthy though.